# Yeoman generator install and get ran from different file locactions

Tags: path, directory, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

Excuse my ignorance as I am still getting comfortable with adding folders to paths. That being said my yeoman generators are being installed to `~/.node/lib/node_modules` and ran my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

How can I change where my yo generators install? Or how to can I add them to my yeoman path?

Answer (score 0):

I just manually dragged them to the other folder

Comment: That's what I had to do just looking for an alternative more efficient way like creating a `node_modules` alias or changing the yeoman installer path